# ArrayAdapter containing a ListView : possible

Tags: android

I've a ListView containg an ArrayAdapter.
This ArrayAdapter contains another ListView. The second listView is not display completly and I've some strange behaviour.

So my question : can we do create a ListView containing itself another listview on each line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You **CANNOT** put `ListView`, `GridView` etc inside each other, or inside a `ScrollView`.
Use an `ExpandableListView` if you'd like grouped items in a list, or please explain further the UI you are trying to achieve.

See my post here: [Showing recursive lists inside a tab view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382875/showing-recursive-lists-inside-a-tab-view/5384222#5384222) for some info on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yes, I changed my code after my post using a ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 0):

Does an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) do what you need?