# Showing recursive lists inside a tab view

Tags: android, list, android-tabhost, tabview

Algorithm question here.

I'm creating an app that shows a legal document, with tabs for navigation (TOC, bookmarks, etc). 
Inside the TOC tab, I need to show a multilevel table of contents. At the 'leaf' of the toc, I need to show a TextView

So, I could have:

tab1: List -> List -> List -> List -> List -> TextView

or

tab1: List -> List -> List -> TextView

or

tab1: List -> TextView

depending on the chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection structure of the book I'm showing.

Now, it doesn't matter how deep you are, the TabHost needs to be ALWAYS PRESENT, to provide the main navigation. (Yes, I asked, and I need to use the tabs, not a menu.)

The question:

How do you implement the recursive List inside the FrameLayout of a tab? Or should I use a ListView styled as tabs and just not use the TabHost?

Ideas?

Thanks!
llappall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Number one you cannot put `ListViews` inside `ListViews`, `ScrollViews`, `GridViews` or anything scrollable for that matter (i.e. a `ListView` item cannot be `ListView`). It might compile, it might run, but the results will not be what you expect or want. This is because a `ListView` cannot have a height which is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`.

You can have a two-level list (`ExpandableListView`) but if you require more levels than that you will have to implement the functionality yourself by extending `ListView` or `ExpandableListView`.

You can also have sectioned lists, and lists with multiple item types, but there is no way using the default SDK components to get a 5-level list.

Number two: Yes you can have a `ListView` inside a `TabHost`. You won't be able to use a `ListActivity`, but that just means you'll have to call the `ListView` methods directly:

```
ListView myList = findViewById(R.id.myList);
myList.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

instead of calling the inbuilt `ListActivity` methods.

Just place your `ListView` inside the `FrameLayout` in your layout file. If you have three tabs and the `ListView` is the first element inside the `FrameLayout`, then it will be displayed as the content for the first tab. If it is the second element, it will be the content for second tab and so on.

The only way you could implement a recursive list with inbuilt components would be to use a single `ListView`, and then change the contents of the adapter of the `ListView` when a user selects an item (essentially a drill-down menu using a single ListView). You'd also need to catch the back button with `onBackPressed` in order to allow the user to navigate back up the list, or provide a back button somewhere.

Comment: Joseph, thanks for the answer.  It's exactly what I was looking to: no easy solutions. The ListView being change by the adapter sounds like the closest to what I want, but the adapter will look monstrous. Thanks!  --Llappall

Comment: Not necessarily. For instance in a simple case if you had one top level menu with 4 second level menus you'd just need an ArrayAdapter<String>, a List<String> and 5 String[]s (containing top menu and 4 sub-menus) and an integer to remember the current level. Just call List.clear(), then List.addAll(String[]) with one of your data-sets, then ArrayAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged() and your list contents will change. Use an onClickListener on your list and in the onClick method decide whether this is item  leads to submenu (in which case load the required dataset) or not (perform the item action)

Comment: In fact you could create an ArrayAdapter<MyObject> where MyObject looked something like `class MyObject { public String itemName; public List<MyObject> childItems; }`. Then when an item is clicked test whether `((MyObject) ListView.getItemAtPosition(position)).childItems == null`. If not then set the `childItems` as the new adapter content. This way you only need to keep track of one parent List<MyObject>, but you will need to set this up somehow in the first place.

Comment: One more comment: to do the 'leaf', which would be a different kind of view (a LinearLayout with two TextViews, say), I could have both the ListView and this View inside the FrameLayout, and call setVisibility(Visibility.GONE) for the one I don't need. Sounds doable this way... :)

Comment: BTW, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me think through this. You're cool!